# ASP.NET MVC: ref long? parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to call a stored procedure, but one of the parameters is "ref long? partyId" and I'm not sure how I'm supposed to pass or not pass something.

What should I be passing in the arguments to either bypass this or appease it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long?` means `Nullable<long>`. The `ref` means it is being passed by reference instead of by value. When you pass the value, you need to include `ref` before the parameter you are passing. Something like this:

```
long? myLong = 0;
myProcedure(ref myLong);
```